# Delphi access violation inside TLanguages utility

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, locale

For some reason, trying to create a TLanguages object provided by the SysUtils header by using the singleton or by calling the constructor directly is causing trouble in the wild, where some users report this error (X varies):

```
Access violation at address X. Write of address X (at address X)
```

... when the following seemingly innocent line of code is executed:

```
TLanguages.Create;
```

To clarify, this is not related to context. I can put this line in any place I like (as the only line of code of an empty program for example), but the problem remains.

The weird part is that this class is part of Delphi's standard headers, which should not fail (right?).

```
constructor TLanguages.Create;
type
  TCallbackThunk = packed record
    POPEDX: Byte;
    MOVEAX: Byte;
    SelfPtr: Pointer;
    PUSHEAX: Byte;
    PUSHEDX: Byte;
    JMP: Byte;
    JmpOffset: Integer;
  end;
var
  Callback: TCallbackThunk;
begin
  inherited Create;
  Callback.POPEDX := $5A;
  Callback.MOVEAX := $B8;
  Callback.SelfPtr := Self;
  Callback.PUSHEAX := $50;
  Callback.PUSHEDX := $52;
  Callback.JMP     := $E9;
  Callback.JmpOffset := Integer(@TLanguages.LocalesCallback) - Integer(@Callback.JMP) - 5;
  EnumSystemLocales(TFNLocaleEnumProc(@Callback), LCID_SUPPORTED);
end;
```

The constructor attempts to use a member function as the EnumSystemLocales callback, which seems to be causing the crashes, because copying the **TLanguages.LocalesCallback** function to global scope and passing that to EnumSystemLocales works perfectly fine.

The struct contains the following Intel x86 assembly, where each item is given by its opcode:

```
pop  edx
mov  eax Self
push eax
push edx
jmp  JmpOffset
```

**Can anyone explain how the trick works and tell me why it's not working as expected?**

Comment: Please [edit] to include the actual error message (including the addresses), and some context for the TLanguages.Create; line. Is that line in your own code, or somewhere else? Posting a single line out of context typically has no meaning to anyone but you, and the line you posted should indeed cause subsequent failures if that's it in it's entirety. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite: the error was already present, but X varies (it depends on the heap status probably). Also, context wasn't the issue. The same problem occurs in any context (including an otherwise empty program). That has been clarified too.

Comment: Please provide a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) since at the moment, I dispute what you assert to be the case in your question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: here's a bare bones example: http://pastebin.com/9VRprgQb. As expected, it contains nothing worth mentioning except that dreaded line. Also, I understand why this all sounds dubious, but affected users can replicate the crash flawlessly, in any code context.

Comment: That should be in the question, not a pastebin. What's more it's way too long. Make it a console app and you can do it in about 7 lines. Please try and do that. All the same, I cannot reproduce. So what is special about the machines on which it fails? And give us an exact error message. Replace the X's with real values. Add madExcept and find out exactly where the AV is raised. We need as much information as possible.

Comment: OK, here's an explanation. The machines on which it fails have enforced mandatory DEP. But it's rather unlikely that this is it. But we can't do much more than guess!

Comment: I'll ask the affected users about the DEP stuff which seems to be a logical explanation (they're not able to execute that record). Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Orwell, this trick is called "stdcall method thunk", allows to pass a method pointer as generic function pointer, working around implicit Self parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be a known issue with older Delphi versions, related to DEP, as I guessed in comments to the question. It's clear that the code in the RTL cannot work when DEP is enabled.

Here's a link to confirm the theory: http://codecentral.embarcadero.com/Item/23411

Although that CodeCentral article includes code to fix the problem in Delphi 5, it looks like it will work in Delphi 7 too. The fix works by hooking the `SysUtils.Languages` function. So make sure you always use that rather than calling `TLanguages.Create` yourself, for obvious reasons.

Comment: Yep, DEP is/was the problem. It's amazing what kind of random causes one runs into when distributing code among masses of people.

Comment: @Orwell, it is not random, your thunk does not reside in the executable memory region. Once you pass its pointer for execution, DEP kicks in.

Comment: +1 - awesome psychic powers! (the OP could have created a small case to reproduce!)